# Better way of checking if MySql datetime is null

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table with a deleted_at datetime column with a default value of '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. I am issuing a query to check for rows which have not been deleted yet (have aforementioned default value). Rather than pass that string construct through the where clause, is there a better way?

I got the following to work, but wanted to see if there was something better:

```
SELECT *, (IF(CAST(deleted_at AS time) IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS deleted FROM unicorn WHERE status_id = 1 HAVING deleted = 0;
```

vs

```
SELECT * FROM unicorn WHERE status_id = 1 AND deleted_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second way works (and I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't) then I would go with that. When you `CAST` your column, MySQL has to convert it first before it can run your query and that involves overhead. The second one contains the actual string to match against. Try running an `EXPLAIN` on your `SELECT` query and you should see the difference.

Comment: Just seems clumsy to have to pass the default datetime string in just to see if a row has been soft deleted. I'll check the explains.